# GPU's fan starts spinning then restart every few second or so

Tags: graphics-card, gpu, nvidia-graphics-card, fan, computer-building

I own a [Nvidia GTX 960 mini](https://www.asus.com/Graphics-Cards/GTX960-MOC-4GD5/). The GPU is working as expected but the fan is doing a strange thing. Every few seconds or so, the fan runs then restart. Start. Stop. Start. Stop. Looping constantly. Here is a gif showcasing the trouble:

[image: gif showcasing pb]

- I tried to reboot the combuter.
- I tried to update the driver without success*.
- I cleaned the GPU's fan with a air duster.
- I tried the GPU on another build. The behavior is still the same.

I didnt find a lot of resource online, but I find a video on [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i9TS1zen1gY) showcasing a similar problem. OP's Video's description is:

> Tested my gpu card on another PC and it still worked. After 2 hours of troubleshooting, turns out it was RAM problem. Cleaning and reinstalling the RAM solved my problem.

I am not sure how it is related since I tried the GPU on another computer. Note that the other computer use the same RAM model than I.

TechPowerUp GPU-Z can output clearly this problem:

[image]

*Driver installed:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me, download the latest driver from Nvidia, do an advanced install, and select fresh install. This should reset any messed up configs. However, I had this happen for a long time and the fan developed a strange noise.

Answer (score -1):

I suppose it's good for you to clean the GPU fan(s).
Are you thinking about air-flow in your computer case/chassis?
Enough air-flow can make your computer cool, as you know.

I recommend to see the temperature of your mother board, CPU, GPU, storage and their fan-speed. Try to use monitoring utilities, such as ***[HW Monitor](https://www.cpuid.com/softwares/hwmonitor.html)***, ***[CoreTemp](https://www.alcpu.com/CoreTemp/)***.

Regards,